# Не переведен текст на странице основного сайта «Задать Вопрос»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, вопросы

Чтобы воспроизвести, откройте ссылку [Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) на основном сайте.

От редактора:

- Поскольку в вопросе два блока текста, **предлагайте варианты отдельно для каждого.**
- в Transifex не нашел нужные строки. Они где-то в другом месте хранятся?

> [image]

Comment: Translated and revived. Thank you for this bugreport.

Answer (score 2):

#### Заголовок

> В чем заключается ваш вопрос для Stack Overflow на русском? Будьте конкретны.

Я бы предпочел не использовать название сайта, то есть такой вариант:

> В чем заключается ваш вопрос? Будьте конкретны.

#### Боковая панель

> Хотите задать вопрос сообществу Stack Overflow на русском?
>
> Мы предпочитаем вопросы, на которые можно дать конкретные ответы, а не те, которые порождают дискуссию.
>
> Предоставьте как можно больше деталей, поделитесь проделанным исследованием.
>
> Если ваш вопрос о самом сайте, пожалуйста, задайте его на Мете.

Нижние ссылки

> - посетите справку.
> - как задавать вопросы.

Comment: Мне тоже нравится заголовок без названия сайта.

Comment: И здесь тоже предлагаю принять перевод.