# Не переведен текст на странице Меты «Задать Вопрос»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, вопросы, нет-в-transifex

Чтобы воспроизвести, откройте ссылку [Задать вопрос на Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) и поставьте курсор в поле заголовка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Для вашего удобства есть [заготовка перевода с оригинальными строками](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1043/181472).

Связанный вопрос: [Не переведен текст на странице основного сайта «Задать Вопрос»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/47/181472)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Боковая панель

> Is your question about the `[Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/)` community or website?
>
> Хотите задать вопрос о сайте `[Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/)`, сообществе или его правилах?

---

> Provide details. Show examples.
>
> Предоставьте как можно больше деталей, подкрепите их примерами.

---

> Whenever possible, link to the relevant questions, answers, users, or page on the site you're discussing.
>
> Во всех случаях, когда это возможно, ссылайтесь на связанные вопросы, ответы, пользователей или конкретные страницы сайта, который вы обсуждаете.

---

> `[visit the help center »](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)`
>
> `[ознакомьтесь с справкой »](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)`

Comment: Поскольку большой активности в ответах нет, предлагаю принять ваши варианты.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, "сообществе или правилах сообщества" лучше заменить на "сообществе или его правилах"

Comment: @Qwertiy: да, так действительно лучше. Позволю себе правку.

Answer (score 1):

#### Заголовок

> What's your bug, feature request or meta-discussion topic? Be specific.

Перевод:

> Опишите найденный дефект, предложение или тему для обсуждения. Будьте конкретны.

Answer (score 0):

Заготовка перевода:

#### Заголовок

> What's your bug, feature request or meta-discussion topic? Be specific.
>
> перевод

#### Боковая панель

> Is your question about the `[Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/)` community or website?
>
> перевод

---

> Provide details. Show examples.
>
> перевод

---

> Whenever possible, link to the relevant questions, answers, users, or page on the site you're discussing.
>
> перевод

---

> `[visit the help center »](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)`
>
> `[перевод »](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)`

Answer (score 0):

#### Заголовок

> What's your bug, feature request or meta-discussion topic? Be specific.
>
> Озаглавьте ваше сообщение об ошибке, предложение или призыв к дискуссии — кратко и точно.

Довольно сильно отклонился от оригинальной формулировки. Но мне кажется, такая инструкция сама по себе более точная и использует возможности русского языка.

Comment: Конец как-то не звучит. Можно было бы переставить в начало, но тогда пропадает акцент на этих словах.

Comment: @Qwertiy: хм. «... к дискуссии в краткой и точной форме»?

Comment: "Be specific" скорее означает "будьте конкретны", в том смысле что не надо писать "какая-то фигня", "помогите". Поблема с "кртако и точно", что это чтосто невозможно в формате заголовка - собственно поэтому помимо заголовка есть тело вопроса, где как раз и набо быть точным и, желательно, кратким, а в самом заголовке достаточно просто быть конкретным.

Comment: @Qwertiy: рациональное замечание. Вот вариант Nicolas как раз использует ваш вариант перевода.

Comment: @Qwertiy: или предлагаете тут добавить такое же вместо «кратко и точно»? http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1206/181472

Comment: Я просто высказал мнение, что сочетание "кратко и точно" лучше отнести к подсказке для вопроса, а не для темы. Дальше уж на твоё усмотрение.

Answer (score 0):

#### Боковая панель

> Is your question about the `[Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/)` community or website?
>
> Относится ли ваш вопрос к сообществу или сайту `[Stack Overflow на русском](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/)`?

---

> Provide details. Show examples.
>
> Сообщите подробности вопроса. Приведите примеры.

---

> Whenever possible, link to the relevant questions, answers, users, or page on the site you're discussing.
>
> Если это возможно, обязательно дайте ссылку на связанные вопросы и ответы, пользователей или страницы сайта, которые вы обсуждаете.

---

> `[visit the help center »](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)`
>
> `[посетите справку »](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help)`

Answer (score 0):

> What's your bug, feature request or meta-discussion topic? Be
>   specific.
>
> Озаглавьте ваше сообщение об ошибке, предложение или призыв к обсуждению. Будьте конкретны.